# How to Pass A Session Variable in Zend To Native PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, session-variables

I want to pass a variable from Zend frame work to a native php file in the same server.

what i tried

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
     if($auth->hasIdentity())
        {

          $user = $auth->getIdentity();
          $username33 = $this->escape(ucfirst($user->username));
          $_SESSION['thisisnotit']=$username33;
       }
```

then i tried this in my php page

```
echo $notit = $_SESSION['thisisnotit'];
```

Obviously this gave me an error. I understand the syntax of sessions in Zend is

```
$myNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myNamespace');
```

but how do i get this to work so that i can access the varible in my php file

Comment: you have to start session first in you php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to get auth service. So, for that or for any service you want, first you need to load ZF2 application to get your auth service.
Following working/tested code to achieve this -

```
require 'init_autoloader.php';
// Run the application!
$app=Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php');
$authService=$app->getServiceManager()->get('AuthenticationService');
echo 'Session Data: <pre>'.print_r($authService->getIdentity(), true);
```

More efficient way is welcome.